# How to deal with Negative Padding Inputs for Pytorch test cases

Tags: pytorch, padding, torch

I'm trying to implement the torch.nn.functional.pad mode = "replicate" with shape= (1,3,4,4) and padding =(-1,1,-2,1). Getting error :

```
Check failed: lhs_padding >= 0 && lhs_padding <= dim_size - 1
Frames:
Info:
    @     0x7fd059fb4810  ef_log::FatalLog::~FatalLog()
    @     0x7fd0d881760c  torch_dtu::ShapeInference::InferReplicationPadBackwardOpShape()
    @     0x7fd0d853cf6f  torch_dtu::Node::replication_pad2d_backward()
    @     0x7fd0d84791c2  torch_dtu::XLANativeFunctions::replication_pad2d_backward()
    @     0x7fd0d8612dcd  c10::impl::wrap_kernel_functor_unboxed_<>::call()
    @     0x7fd13dbd4980  at::_ops::replication_pad2d_backward::redispatch()
    @     0x7fd13f44ec71  torch::autograd::VariableType::(anonymous namespace)::replication_pad2d_backward()
    @     0x7fd13f44f24c  c10::impl::wrap_kernel_functor_unboxed_<>::call()
    @     0x7fd13dc3e36e  at::_ops::replication_pad2d_backward::call()
    @     0x7fd13f1d889a  torch::autograd::generated::ReplicationPad2DBackward0::apply()
    @     0x7fd13f8baaf7  torch::autograd::Node::operator()()
    @     0x7fd13f8b5d5b  torch::autograd::Engine::evaluate_function()
    @     0x7fd13f8b6a8a  torch::autograd::Engine::thread_main()
    @     0x7fd13f8ae4a9  torch::autograd::Engine::thread_init()
    @     0x7fd153576a33  torch::autograd::python::PythonEngine::thread_init()
    @     0x7fd1546036df  +0xbd6de)
    @     0x7fd1579196db  start_thread
    @     0x7fd157c5261f  clone
```

Can anybody help me with this negative padding issue?

Answer (score 0):

This error is telling you that the padding values you have provided are invalid.

In the `pad` function, the `padding` argument is a tuple of four integers representing the number of padding elements to add on each side of the input tensor. The `lhs_padding` value that is mentioned in the error message refers to the padding on the left side of the tensor along the first dimension. The `dim_size` value refers to the size of the first dimension of the input tensor.

In your case, you have provided a negative padding value of -1 for the left side of the tensor along the first dimension. This is not allowed because the padding value must be non-negative and must not exceed the size of the dimension minus 1.

To fix this error, you will need to make sure that the padding values you provide are non-negative and do not exceed the size of the corresponding dimensions minus 1.

Comment: but how do I implement the negative padding for a backward pass?

Comment: In this error code, only this information can be given. add your main code